# Машинное обучение Python

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Есть набор данных:

```
    A   B    C   D
0   18  13   8   1
0   15  12   9   1
0   12  18   1   0
0   11  19   4   0
..................
100 17  11   6   1
```

Данные в столбцах A, B, C произвольные, D равно или 1 или 0.
Подскажите, какие темы по ML стоит изучить, чтобы обучиться по этим данным. Получается обучение с учителем, мы по данным в столбце D, должны понять в каком диапазоне в дальнейшем должны быть данные в A, B, C, чтобы D было равно 1, и какие чтобы 0.

Comment: Вам нужны алгоритмы для решения задачи бинарной классификации)

Comment: Спасибо)) Можете посоветовать какую-то конкретную книгу по этой теме? (если знаете, конечно)

Comment: Книги не посоветую - я предпочитаю онлайн курсы. С точки зрения практики могу посоветовать сравнение разніх классификаторов: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html

Comment: Благодарю) попробую разобраться.